# Writing cucumber test cases

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber, automated-tests, frank

I am trying to lear how to write test scripts for frank ( cucumber test scripts).

This is what I have written

```
When I navigate to "aaa"
Then I should be on the aaa screen
Then I navigate to "bob"
Then I should be on the bob screen 

When /^I navigate to "(.*?)"$/ do |aaa|
  touch "view:'UITabBarButton' marked:'aaa'"
END

Then /^I should be on the aaa screen$/ do
  check_element_exists "view:'UIImageView' marked:'xxx'"
END

Then /^navigating to "(.*?)"$/ do |bbb|
  touch "view:'UITabBarButton' marked:'bbb'"
end

Then /^I SHould be on the bbb screen$/ do
   check_element_exists "view:'UIImageView' marked:'zzz'"
end
```

where the letters are written instead of the view/picture names

This is what i get while running the script

/Users/janogrodowczyk/SMHI/ios/ios/Frank/features/step_definitions/test_steps.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND (SyntaxError)

And i have no idea what i am doing wrong since the first 2 rows

```
When I navigate to "aaa"
Then I should be on the aaa screen
```

are working fine when only they are run without the rest.

Best Regards

Answer (score 4):

`END` and `end` are different ruby keywords.

`END` represents code to be executed before the end of a program.

`end` designates the end of a class, method, control structure, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Navigating to "aaa" and "bbb" is actually two scenarios. You can't "navigate" again in one scenario.

So, firstly refactor your steps from

```
When I navigate to "aaa"
Then I should be on the aaa screen
Then I navigate to "bob"
Then I should be on the bob screen
```

To:

```
Given blah blah
When I navigate to "aaa"
Then I should be on the aaa screen

Given blah blah
When I navigate to "bbb"
Then I should be on the bbb screen
```

But, wait. Why duplicate? `Scenario Outline" could help you to test similar cases.

```
Scenario Outline: Visit UI
Given blah blah
When I navigate to <link>
Then I should see <screen_name> screen

Examples:
  | link | screen_name |
  | aaa  | aaa screen  |
  | bbb  | bbb screen  |
  | ccc  | ccc screen  |
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it works fine but I have an issue while writing longer scripts.

Comment: Thanks it works fine, butt how do I do to write longer scripts, I keep getting different kinds of syntax errors. Should I create a new file or can everything be written in the same?

Comment: My pleasure:) For new question of "longer scripts", I don't quite understand. Do you mean adding more Scenarios? You can just add multiple Scenarios in to one feature file, as long as they are about same feature. You can also create as many feature files as you like.